# Enable show as conversation in outlook programatically

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-2010

i am creating an Outlook add-in where i need to enable Conversation view in inbox folder("Show as Conversation") in outlook.i tried through registry Key ("Upgrade To Conversations"),but still i didn't get that.

i tried as following

```
RegistryKey rkconversations = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Office" + OLVersion + @"\Outlook\Setup");

 rkconversations.SetValue("UpgradeToConversations", "1", RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```

i aslo tried like this:

```
 Outlook.Views views = inbox.Views;
                Outlook.View view = views["Hide Reading Pane"];

                if (view != null)
                    view.Delete();

                Outlook.View view1 = views.Add("Hide Reading Pane", Outlook.OlViewType.olTableView,
                    Outlook.OlViewSaveOption.olViewSaveOptionThisFolderOnlyMe);
                tableView = view1 as Outlook.TableView;
                tableView.ShowReadingPane = false;
                tableView.ShowConversationByDate = true;
                tableView.ShowConversationSendersAboveSubject = true;
                tableView.ShowFullConversations = true;
                view1.Save();
                view1.Apply();
```

Show as Conversations is not enabled

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the required modifications in Outlook manually. Then take a look at the [XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.view.xml.aspx) property of the View/TableView object and compare it with your own. Thus, you may find the missed point.